# connecting external hard drive to Thunderbolt connector, via Micro-B USB 3.0 to USB-C cable

Tags: windows, external-hard-drive, thinkpad, usb-c, thunderbolt

Is it safe / possible to connect a "standard" USB-compatible external hard drive, to the *Thunderbolt 3* connector of my *Windows* machine (*Lenovo ThinkPad P15*), via *Micro-B USB 3.0 to USB-C* cable?

Or should the external drive should be somewhat Thunderbolt-compatible or something of that sort?

The cable I'm referring to:
[image]

Comment: Although I have zero actual experience with TB3, but AFAIK / according to Wikipedia, (all) TB3 supports USB 3.1 gen 2 (which is backward-compatible with older/slower USB devices). Btw, I think you meant [this](https://www.ugreen.com/products/usb-c-to-usb-3-0-micro-b-cable), otherwise you'll need an extra type-C male to type-A female adapter (or hub). (One of the pictures states that it `work with all TB3 laptops`.)

Comment: @TomYan 1) Thank you very much for the correction! My bad. 2) Got it, thank you! It's just that I've read on some forums that Thunderbolt is "it's own thing" and it shouldn't be mistaken for a USB-C port (== USB-C devices shouldn't be connected to it). So, to avoid compatibility / potential power-related issues -- I wanted to be sure.

Comment: I have connected SSD to USB3 ports using adapters. The adapter for SATA to USB3 worked great for SSD, but HDD would not even power up. Not enough power for HDD. Best, if HDD to have external power supply and not rely on USB power.

Comment: @golosovsky Well, "its own thing" refers to the fact that it can also provide PCIe an DP connection additionally, or in other words, TB3 is essentially a superset. (For the record, TB1 and TB2 does not provide USB support; its physical connector isn't USB anyway.)